# JBoss with idea

Tags: jboss, intellij-idea

I am trying to setup idea for JSF development (i am new to JSF) and we are using jBoss as server. I added the jBoss as application server in idea and tried to run a simple 'hello world' application but I get the following errors

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Disconnected from server
```

But when I run the jboss server from bin\standalone.bat the server runs !
Why is it giving me the error in idea ?

Comment: The problem seems to be about integration between your IDE and the JBoss, maybe it's not giving enough memory when starting it. Check for the initialization parameters from your IDE when running the JBoss server instance. (Note: this is not a JSF directly related problem).

Comment: Try to use 64-bit JVM instead of the 32-bit one (change the project JDK), this error occurs because your default VM options (probably defined via the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable) are too high for your system. More details are available in [this knowledge base document](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393413).